# Copying 1 column of filtered data to another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am having some trouble with my VBA code that I am writing to replace a manual process.

I have almost got to the end of it but I am struggling to get the code to copy my filtered data to a new sheet on a column by column basis (the layout changes in the new sheet). The code I currently have is only copying the data in cell C2.

Could anyone have a look at this and see where I have gone wrong? I have copied the relevant part of the code below.

Thanks in advance

```
    'Copy formula down

 Range("F2:L2").Select
 Selection.Copy
 LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 Range("F2:L2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:L" & LR), Type:=xlFillDefault

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("O1").goalseek Goal:=Range("Q1"), ChangingCell:=Range("U1")

'Add Filter
Range("A2").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$L$5000").AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:= _
    "1"

'Move the data to the new sheet

Sheets("Sheet1").Select
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
NextFree = Range("A2:A" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
Range("A" & NextFree).Select
Range("A" & NextFree).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value2 = _
Worksheets("To Be Used").Range("C:C").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value2

'This part is only copying the data from cell C2 when I need it to copy all of the filtered data     in column C aprt from C1 and there is a long delay

Range("A" & NextFree).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value2 = _
Worksheets("To Be Used").Range("C2:C" & LR).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value2
```

Comment: Hi-I have just realised I have entered a part of the code twice, the part at the bottom is the code I tried to use and amended to the code above the comment but neither work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tightened up your code a smidge but I'm afraid I was unable to adequately test the `.goalseek` functionality. The filter and subsequent copy/paste of the filtered column C works as expected.

```
Dim rw As Long, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Sheet16")  'change the target worksheet name here
With Sheets("To Be Used").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    .Cells(2, 6).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 7).FillDown
    .Range("O1").GoalSeek Goal:=.Range("Q1"), ChangingCell:=.Range("U1")
    .AutoFilter
    .AutoFilter Field:=12, Criteria1:="1"
    If Application.Subtotal(103, .Columns(3)) > 1 Then
        rw = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Row
        .Columns(3).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 1).Copy _
          Destination:=ws.Cells(rw, 1)
        .Columns(1).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 2).Copy _
          Destination:=ws.Cells(rw, 2)
        .Columns(4).Offset(1, 0).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, 2).Copy _
          Destination:=ws.Cells(rw, 4)
    End If
    .AutoFilter
End With
Set ws = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks this works a treat!! I am trying to use the code you have written to copy further columns but I am not getting anywhere, could you help? I am looking to copy columns 1 & 2 from the 1st sheet into column 2 & 3 of the "sheet16" and the column 4 & 5 into columns 4 & 5 of the new sheet. Thanks

Comment: @Steven Craig - Modified for additional columns above. The target worksheet's name only has to be changed in one place on the second line.